# Proving Lebesgue’s criterion for Riemann integrablility without compactness

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, riemann-integration

I am looking for a proof of Lebesgue’s criterion for Riemann integrablility that does not involve compactness. This is due to the reason that the syllabus I teach consists of the theorem but not the notion of compactness.

Can you suggest any such resource?

Comment: Do you mean the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma?

Comment: f is integrable on [a, b] if and only if the set of discontinuity points of f is a zero set. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Right. That's Lebesgue’s criterion for Riemann integrablility.

Comment: This link is from East Tennessee State University, and it offers a possible proof. The first mention of the word "compact" is in an exercise. I think it might be what you are looking for. [Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/Riemann-Lebesgue-Theorem.pdf)

Comment: it did use compactness

Comment: Very odd that you don't have properties of compact sets and yet you are trying to prove Lebesgue's criterion?